# Terraform --reconfigure

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have  question about the upgrade process further, as I got that error about "Failed to decode current backend config" is it possible to run the terraform init --reconfigure with no risk if I want to roll back to the version 0.12 (from 0.13) as I have both versions installed on my pc at the moment?

Comment: are you managing resources or do you just want to start fresh and ignore your existing state file?

Answer (score 14):

The `-reconfigure` argument to `terraform init` tells Terraform to entirely ignore the working directory's current backend configuration and to re-initialize with only what's in the `backend` block in your root module.

This is essentially the same as removing the `.terraform` subdirectory (where Terraform tracks the working directory internals) and then running `terraform init`. The difference is that removing the whole `.terraform` directory will discard *all* of the working directory information -- including your currently-selected external modules, if any -- whereas `-reconfigure` only tells Terraform to ignore the backend settings in particular.

If your `backend` block has all of the settings required to initialize the backend and you've not changed those settings since the last time you ran `terraform init` there is no harm in running with `-reconfigure`.

However, if you previously ran `terraform init` with any `-backend-config` arguments, or if you have changed the `backend` block settings since the last time you ran `terraform init`, running with `-reconfigure` will discard the previous settings entirely.

Comment: Thank you! Hashicorp Terraform needs to hire you for your clear translation of their documentation @MartinAtkins!